# How to keep rows extended in table in Element UI

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I have a draggable table from element-ui:

```
 <table-card>
      <el-table-draggable @drop="changeDossiertypesOrder" handle=".handler">
        <el-table
          :data="dossiertypes"
          v-loading="dossiertypesLoading"
          row-key="id"
          :expand-row-keys="expandRowKeys"
          @expand-change="handleExpandChange"
        >
          <el-table-column type="expand">
</el-table-column>
        </el-table>
      </el-table-draggable>
    </table-card>

<el-dialog      
  :visible.sync="modalVisibility"
  :close-on-click-modal="false"
  :show-close="false"
  @open="resetForm"
  @opened="$refs.defaultField[0].focus()"
  @closed="resetForm"
>

  <template v-slot:footer>
    <div>
      <c-button type="primary" icon="check" @click="saveType" :loading="isSaving.editType">Save
      </c-button>
    </div>
  </template>
</el-dialog>
```

SO currently, after I clicked the button (showEditType) and after I edit & save, all the extended rows are going back to their own initial state. After I click the button, I want all the opened rows stay extended again.

this is the handle

```
handleExpandChange(row, expandedRows) {
      const id = row.id;
      const lastId = this.expandRowKeys[0];
      // disable mutiple row expanded
      this.expandRowKeys = id === lastId ? [] : [id];
    },
```

And here is my saveType function
saveType() {
this.isSaving.editType = true;

```
  axios
    .put()
    .then(() => {
      this.expandRowKeys = [...this.expandRowKeys];
    })
    .finally(() => {
      this.isSaving.editType = false;
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue too. I solved it by adding `:row-key="row_key"` into `el-table` tag

Also, add row_key method:

```
row_key(row) {
     return row.id
}
```

Hopefully this helps, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add property to expand all rows by default. see table properties [here](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#table-attributes)

**Property:** Set property `default-expand-all` as `<el-table :default-expand-all="true">`

this will make all rows expanded by default, but if you want to keep them close first and then expanded, you can pass a boolean variable.